# How to reformat all columns to be hyperlinked in apple numbers?

Tags: formatting, iwork-numbers, hyperlink

I have a large spreadsheet where one of the columns has text hyperlinks. They are not clickable though.

I can make them clickable by selecting url text and clicking Insert -> hyperlinks -> webpage.

But this is really tedious if i do it manually. Is there a way to apply this on the entire column?

Answer (score 1):

Apple Numbers had this problem since day one. The easiers way to convert is to copy entire column and paste in text edit (plain text mode) then copy and paste back. It does not work on large collumns. If you have more then 500 cells it will probably not going to work, so try to copy and paste small number of cells. Try 200 or 300 and see if that helps.